# Are datasets different?

Tags: modeling

In the experiment we measure some parameter $y$ as function of other parameter $x$ at different times (conditions) obtaining ${x_i,y_i}$. However the datasets seems to depend on time when we have taken them, but I have no tool for prove or disapprove my hypothesis. Are there any?

For simplicity lets consider two datasets ${x^1_i,y^1_i}$ and ${x^2_i,y^2_i}$ with equal errors ($\Delta x_i,\Delta y_i = \Delta$). How can I say if both datasets describes the same physical situation?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are concerned about some confounding factor(like physical conditions, time, temp etc) other than the variables you are interested in, influencing the relationship between the X and Y. This issue is typically handled using blocking in experimental design. You design the experiment by constructing blocks of units that are similar in terms of hypothesized confounding factors.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_block_design
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_(statistics)